# How do I convert existing forms to fillable PDF's?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, conversion, installed-programs, webbrowser-app

I know a [solution for Windows](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/convert-word-excel-paper-pdf-forms.html), but I don't know a solution for Linux. The tool for Windows is for **free** and does the conversion **automatically**. I would like to have a software for Linux, which does the same.

Or if you know a solution for my browser it would be great too.

Comment: I guess you could **say** it is **free** after you **purchase** acrobat DC

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Libreoffice** **Writer** to create the form and export to fillable PDF.

[Libreoffice webpage](https://www.libreoffice.org)

First of all,  open **Writer** and create a new document. Select "*View*" from toolbar menu, go to "*Toolbar*" and select "*Form Control*".

Now you can create your form.

Once you have finished, go to "*File*" and "*Export to PDF*". Remember to check "*Create PDF form*" option.

Comment: …and similarly, it works with OpenOffice as well. In either case, the resulting PDF is pretty good, and the form usable. You may need Acrobat to add more functionality (logic etc.) to the form, however.